# IE comment not rendering css on the page at all

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, comments

This is my website, it works fine on chrome, firefox and IE 9. When i try it on IE 7 & IE 8 the IE comments that I use for css is not showing at all. My website: http://www.chan-leung.com

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ieHacks.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ieHacks7.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    <![endif]-->
```

The css files works fine locally, but when i upload to my hosting, the css doesn't show. I'm using IE debugger for browser testing (for IE). The F12 key for IE. When i try to look up ieHacks.css & ieHacks7.css, nothing is showing. I'm stump as to what would be the reason why the ie comments is not working.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stupid thing, but you're sure they're on the server? I couldn't load them at all, direct URL or otherwise. Kept getting 404.

Comment: http://www.chan-leung.com/css/iehacks.css, http://www.chan-leung.com/css/iehacks7.css.
I'm sure i loaded it.

Comment: using the direct url it loads, but not the file path

Comment: Maybe the problem is I was looking up 'css/ieHacks.css', with an *uppercase* "h." My bad.

Comment: You were right, it was syntax error, TY for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have names the css files incorrectly?

You site is maybe trying to use css/ieHacks.css and css/ieHacks7.css but the actual files are css/iehacks.css and css/iehacks7.css

Also try using absolute urls and see if it makes a difference e.g:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/iehacks.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/iehacks7.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->
```

Also, just a note, you are doing a more general assignment first and another more specfic one second, was this intended? The first css file will be applied to ie7 as well as the second, more specific one.

**UPDATE:**

Your site css seems to be the following which isn't like you said in your question:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iehacks.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iehacks7.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->
<!-- [if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: yes, the problem was name I used for the css was wrong.

Yes the css order was intended as you see it. I wanted to only apply the necessary css for the specific browser

Comment: In that case can you mark my solution as correct...? Seeing as it is :)